# Parse string to localdatetime

Tags: java

I have an strange problem when parse a string to a localdatetime

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME;
         LocalDateTime.parse("00:00",formatter);
    }

}
```

Give me:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '00:00' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 00:00 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(Unknown Source)
    at Main.main(Main.java:9)
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 00:00 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.from(Unknown Source)
    at java.time.format.Parsed.query(Unknown Source)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.time.DateTimeException: Unable to obtain LocalDate from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 00:00 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.LocalDate.from(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

I want to parse an String with format "hour:minutes" to a localdatetime (24H format). I don't care what month/year/day is asigned, i only want the time.

Comment: Seems that you data "00:00" is not compatible with the format imposed by ISO_LOCAL_TIME.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I don't care what month/year/day is asigned, i only want the time.

That suggests you *should* be parsing it as a `LocalTime`, given that that's what the string actually represents. You can then add any `LocalDate` to it to get a `LocalDateTime`, if you *really* want to pretend you've got more information then you have:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.format.*;

public class Test {    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME;
        LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("00:00",formatter);
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.of(2000, 1, 1);
        LocalDateTime dateTime = date.atTime(time);
        System.out.println(dateTime); // 2000-01-01T00:00
    }
}
```

If you can avoid creating a `LocalDateTime` at all and just work with the `LocalTime`, that would be even better.

Comment: Oh, i didn't know about LocalTime class.